# How to use EnumWindows with a COM wrapper in VBScript

Tags: c++, winapi, vbscript, com, enumerate

I am writing a Windows API COM wrapper to be used in VBScript, and came up with a problem with callback controlled functions such as `EnumWindows`.

This is what I have currently:

```C++
STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_EnumWindows(BSTR lpEnumFunc, int lParam, int *Result)
{
    *Result = int(EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC(lpEnumFunc), lParam))

    return S_OK;

}
```

But, as I expected this didn't work and when I use this with VBScript, it crashes.

How can I export `EnumWindows` from my COM wrapper to use in VBScript and will VBScript support using it? If so, how can I use `EnumWindowsProc` callback function in VBScript?

**UPDATE**

```C++
BSTR WindowClassName = SysAllocString(L"");
WCHAR WindowTitle[8192];

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(
    __in HWND hWnd,
    __in LPARAM lParam
)
{
    RealGetWindowClass(hWnd, WindowClassName, 100);
    GetWindowText(hWnd, WindowTitle, 8192);

    if (0 == wcscmp(WindowClassName, L"#32768"))
    {
        //<< NOW, HWND need to be caught by WSH and then show it. (I.E. WScript.Echo HWND) >>
    }

    return TRUE;
}

STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_EnumWindows(int lParam)
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, lParam);

    return S_OK;
}
```

```VBScript
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")
WINAPI.WinAPI_EnumWindows 0
```

Now I did above, but instead of this, I need WSH to know if a handle to specified window type is found and return `HWND` internally and show it from WSH, not directly from C++.(such as via a Message Box).

This function's `lParam` parameter can be set from VBScript, but how can I set `EnumWindowsProc`? Can it be done using `GetRef` or something similar in VBSript? But `GeRef` allows only one parameter. I want this `EnumWindowsProc` callback function also to be declared in VBScript, otherwise wrapping this function becomes useless.

I read [this](http://alax.info/blog/1381) post from @Alex.K's comment and found it very useful, but I can't understand how to use it with `EnumWindows`'s callback `EnumWindowsProc`.

Please help me more on this.

Comment: See http://alax.info/blog/1381 - Other options not mentioned there are to raise an event that gets caught in VBScript (using the 2nd argument of the (non WScript) CreateObject() function) or of course to enum in the server and just return something that contains a list of whatever you need.

Comment: @AlexK. I found your link very useful, but I still can't understand its use with `EnumWindows`. :-|